# Windows 8 does not show cur image

Tags: windows, image, windows-8, vb6

My application uses some .cur file. It works properly in all Windows OS other than window 8. In windows i get error like

```
Run-time error '481':
Invalid picture
```

This is the code I am running:

```
Dim pic As StdPicture
Set pic = LoadPicture("D:\Arrow.cur")
Me.AutoRedraw = True
Me.PaintPicture pic, 10, 10
```

Even this sample code for a cur file gives same error. So please help to solve the problem.

Comment: I tried to open a CUR file in VB6 installed on Windows 7 and it gave me the same error message. Are you sure CUR files are supported at all? What native Windows application can view CUR files?

Comment: @Ahmad I don't know whether CUR files are supported. I didn't get any information about it after searching in google. So i posted here.

Comment: I found this http://filext.com/file-extension/CUR

Comment: Windows certainly supports .CUR files.  I'd guess the problem might be the format of the file, which might use a color depth or something else that isn't supported.  I tried a VB6 program with a custom color cursor here on Win7 SP1, works *just fine*.  Of course to see color instead of monochrome you need to load it from a resource, as long ago documented in a *very* old MS KB article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/267849

Comment: BTW:  The VB and VS 6.0 CDs include an optional tool called Imagedit.exe that can view, edit, and create .CUR files.